# Python dictionaries changing values in other dictionaries, bug?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting output that I'm not expecting with this code:

```
class Band:
    zones = {}
class Zone:
    count = 0

global_zones = {}

global_zones[1] = Band()
global_zones[2] = Band()
global_zones[1].zones[3302] = Zone()
global_zones[2].zones[3302] = Zone()

print('b4 1/3302',global_zones[1].zones[3302].count)
print('b4 2/3302',global_zones[2].zones[3302].count)

global_zones[1].zones[3302].count += 1

print('af 1/3302',global_zones[1].zones[3302].count)
print('af 2/3302',global_zones[2].zones[3302].count)
```

Output:

```
b4 1/3302 0
b4 2/3302 0
af 1/3302 1
af 2/3302 1
```

Expected Output:

```
b4 1/3302 0
b4 2/3302 0
af 1/3302 1
af 2/3302 0
```

Why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You're using the same `zones` dictionary in all `Band` instances. Make it an instance variable instead of a class variable.

Comment: so python uses static variables by default?  care to post an answer showing how to make it an instance variable?

Comment: It does what  you tell it to do. Instance variables are assigned to attributes of `self`. Variables that aren't `self` attributes will be static class variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Band:
    def __init__(self):
        self.zones = {}
class Zone:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

global_zones = {}

global_zones[1] = Band()
global_zones[2] = Band()
global_zones[1].zones[3302] = Zone()
global_zones[2].zones[3302] = Zone()

print('b4 1/3302',global_zones[1].zones[3302].count)
print('b4 2/3302',global_zones[2].zones[3302].count)

global_zones[1].zones[3302].count += 1

print('af 1/3302',global_zones[1].zones[3302].count)
print('af 2/3302',global_zones[2].zones[3302].count)
```

Thanks to @Barmar for the suggestion in the comments.